# Can Wordpress co-exist with existing database tables?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site for a client. Their hosting only allows 1 SQL database which already contains a table (named gallery) which is used on their current site.

Is it safe for me to import the SQL for the Wordpress tables to the existing database?

I assume that as long as the table names are unique, there shouldn't be a problem but want to double-check before taking the plunge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when installing wordpress, it gives you the option to add a prefix to the table names, so you can start all tables with 'tbl_' or any other prefix to make it unique to the existing tables.

[image]

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress-installation.htm

The tutorial shows setting the "Table Prefix", which by 'wp_' is default for wordpress installs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be no Problem.

Wordpress uses 'wp_' as table prefix so as long as you have no existing tables using this prefix there should be no complications.

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix wordpress table names, for ex. wp_***